# Spring Boot Thymeleaf th:include dynamic templates

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using Spring Boot v1.5.2.RELEASE and Thymeleaf.

I use `<div th:include="praxis/header"></div>`.
It works fine, but now I have a special requirement that I want to include a path in the controller like this:

```
<div th:include="praxis/header"></div>

@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/praxis")
public class UserController extends BaseController {
@GetMapping(value = "/header")
    public ModelAndView praxisHeader(HttpServletRequest request) {
        //do sth
        return new ModelAndView("some other templates", "user", user);
    }
}
```

It does not work because th:include can only include templates from the "resource" folder.

How can I include a template from the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`th:include` can only include fragments from other templates, it cannot include data from the controller.

If you want to send data from the controller to the template you should create a map, set the content you want to send as the value of some key in this map, and send this map as `model` using this API:

```
public ModelAndView(String viewName, Map<String,?> model)
```

Now, you have it in the template and you can use it in any way you want.

Comment: sorry response late,i resolved this problem with your help,thanks a lot :) . I write a controller `code`(@Controller @RequestMapping(path = "/praxis")) and return a model `code`(ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("praxis/space", "user", user);) and in this page use `code`(<div th:include="praxis/header"></div>) ,it works.